# Why was this answer heavily edited, and should it be reverted?

Tags: discussion, edits

I recently came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25336738/895810) which solved a problem I had and made a slight [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25336738/5) that I felt was needed.

I know that often edits are "audited", and, out of curiosity, I refreshed the page to see that another user (@user2357112supports Monica) had (in my opinion) [heavily edited the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25336738/revisions) ([Revision 6](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25336738/6)) to the point that it didn't resemble the original answer which contained very useful information.

I feel they should have created a new answer, not edited a valid answer.

Should this be reverted?

---

If an answer is significantly edited, such that the author wouldn't recognize it as being their own, why not remove the original author's name from it? These are real people contributing, and we're assuming they want this answer attributed to them. If we're going to allow the "community" to hijack an answer and change the author's own words, it should be more clear than seeing "edited by..." at the bottom. By allowing edits such as this, we're essentially changing the perception of this author's skills and thoughts to the entire internet.

Comment: *"I feel they should have created a new answer, not edit a valid answer"* ... that's correct. If that user had less than 2k reputation, then the edit would (/should) be rejected as "clearly against authors intent".

Comment: yes, https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica shoudl have made his own answer and downvote the answer and or comment it

Comment: I've rolled back to rev 5, since Rev 6 definitely changes the author's intent. I'm not sure about your edit though, does that invalidate [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44932681)? It's generally preferable not to do that. (If you're just making corrections without invalidating other answers, that's fine).

Comment: @cigien, I didn't go down that far and see [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44932681/895810).  though technically it doesn't answer the original question, and by itself (without context of the answer I edited) would cause confusion. (if that makes sense) - in other words it should have been a comment or edit, not an answer

Comment: The "very useful information" in the previous version of the answer was wrong. `tee` doesn't work like that. It's just a worse version of `list` if you use it that way.

Comment: The previous version of the answer gives the misleading impression that `tee` avoids saving all the elements in memory, or does something else useful for large inputs. It only does that for use cases where you're iterating over both tees at the same time, like `for thing, next_thing in zip(tee1, islice(tee2, 1))`. If you're looping over the input twice in sequence, `tee` offers no benefit.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, in your opinion is the answer wrong? or just not efficient?  either way I feel you should have downvoted and made a comment and added another answer. it's an answer with 52 upvotes, and no down votes, and the answer does answer the original question (regardless of if it's a "Good" answer)

Comment: It's wrong about `tee` being "a better idea", and it wrongly implies the existence of benefits that do not exist. Multiple commenters have pointed this out, but the answerer has done nothing.

Comment: The first "tee isn't useful here" comment was left the same day the answer was posted. Over 7 years later, it has accumulated 4 upvotes, including mine. The next comment, giving more details about why `tee` isn't useful here and when it is useful, got no upvotes until I upvoted it. People just don't pay attention to that kind of thing. Adding a third "tee isn't useful here" response would be unlikely to actually accomplish anything.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica you might consider outlining your rational for making the edit in an answer to this meta post rather than an extended stream of comments.

Comment: You should not have changed code in an answer. That changes intent. Edit only to clarify what is intended. If you disagree with what was intended then comment and/or answer.

Comment: The whole "conflicts with author's intent" thing makes no sense, anyway. The author's intent was almost certainly not "be wrong". The intent was much more likely "provide a more efficient alternative to `list` for long iterators". They did not achieve that intent, due to a misunderstanding of `tee`. The edit achieves that intent. The rollback does not.

Comment: Every author hopes to be right, so if that were a valid reasoning, we'd only need one answer that keeps getting updated, because the original author's intent was not to be wrong. No, if you have a better approach, you should post it as a separate answer. The author's intent is what they *thought* was right, and the correction shouldn't change that idea, even if it was wrong.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica was your intent to edit because you generally agree with the author but you thought their description would be misinterpreted, or do you believe the answer to be wrong and or detrimental to the community?

Comment: @ChrisSchaller The first part of that answer is correct, but the final section about `tee` is misleading, and their example code using `tee` is exactly the situation when you should *not* use `tee`.

Comment: Keeping the answer using `tee` while adding a separate, more efficient and detailed answer also has added value for those users who already know something but not everything about `tee`. Pretending that the answer about `tee` never existed might only cause new readers to comment things like "you should use tee, it's more efficient" and the discussion would start over with less structure.

Comment: I don't like this line of reasoning, that "SO says not to try to maintain the quality of answers so I guess we'll give up". This is a well documented problem with SE's system and we all know it leads to mistakes, bad practices, and security issues getting shoved in search engine results. I think we should not lie to ourselves and say "this is fine because votes will straighten it out" (they don't). If the answerer doesn't care, edit it. *Who cares what they intended?* Just because SE says we should does not mean we have to, the edit police aren't going to kick down somebody's door.

Comment: Re the EDIT section you appended to your question, your suggestion that the name of the person who originally answered be removed if _"an answer is significantly edited"_ is fine in principle, but the devil is in the details. What constitutes a question being _"significantly edited"_? Who decides? And a even minor change to code in an asnwer can surely be a significant edit, especially if it breaks the code.

Comment: Most commenters who defend this type of editing, seem to assume that they couldn't possibly be wrong about their assessment of the answer, and take it for granted that their edit will straighten things out. Shouldn't this assessment be made by the community through the voting system? That is why it is important to post answers separately.

Comment: @trincot Yes, the edit could be wrong. The answerer could be wrong [and very wrong answers get hundreds of votes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23391839). If the edit's wrong, edit it again. If there's an edit war, flag or make a meta topic about it (like this). It would be nice if SE made this easier, but sadly they kinda punted on this problem at first, they started to think about it now, but in the meantime I think we shouldn't avoid using the tools that we have available. Wikipedia allows anyone to edit, but their pages aren't all spam and nonsense.

Comment: Alternatively people can form 200 strong voting mobs (mobs can be wrong too!), but that's a lot of work and coordination. I can throw out lots of ideas for things SE "should have done" (e.g., some mechanism for turning answers the author doesn't care about anymore into community wiki), the "versioned answer" SE is kicking around is interesting but it doesn't cover answers that aren't now, and never were correct, they were just *first* (sometimes by a thin margin).

Comment: @trincot this community of yours is mostly consists of students, interns or passers by who basically have no clue. There are thousands horible answers in Stack Overflow thanks to that clueless "community". Stripping a rare professional of their right to correct a mistake is the worst thing the Stack Overflow bureaucracy is guilty for.

Comment: As far as I know there are no "certified professional" badges yet. That remains a subjective qualification. Stack Overflow must do all they can to make sure the voting system promotes good answers in the long run. I'm sure there is room for improvement there. It is my personal experience that often the votes do their job in the long run. I have posted several answers to years-old questions that already had several answers with some popular ones, and now my answer has more votes than those. That a much-later answer becomes the most popular is not as rare as is suggested here.

Comment: @jrh This behavior is new, and a corner SO meta painted itself into. There's nothing on the help center that says that you can't do it. [There has](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313762/792066) [been discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153279/213575) [about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306786/792066) [this issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356840/792066), but the employee that served as voice of reason was let go by the company. The other one that [showed interest in this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575) was met with internal pushback too.

Comment: @trincot your experience is still n=1. There was a push years back to address the worst examples, and the results are still undesired [as it took years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293930/792066) to address meaningfully and even then, it wasn't a cookie cutter solution. We had to edit answers to fix them still. So, saying that votes alone fix the thing, is not wrong, but the cost of doing so is way too high.

Comment: Sure, personal experience is just anekdotal, I agree. My preference would be to work on improvements to give new answers better chances to get noticed, and receive votes (or get quickly downvoted). There are many ideas one can think of, and many can be found in the links you shared, @Braiam. In this age of AI, it should be possible to improve on this.

Comment: @trincot AI may solve many problems, but right now, the easiest solution that doesn't need investment on new tech is clicking edits ;)

Comment: Keeping fingers crossed that this kind of editing is only done by users who are good at their stuff.

Comment: @trincot we're all dependent on the kindness of strangers. Some of them research more than others, SE optimizes for the ones that throw out answers fast, and sets that half baked answer in stone, but we don't have to go along with it. We all know the Fastest Gun in the West problem, not a big surprise that a platform with that much pressure on answering fast has a quality problem with answers.

Comment: @Braiam interesting thanks. My respect for Shog went up even more now. I would very much prefer his "use your brain" guidelines. I don't know if people realize how dark of a statement it is, to say "People from the community might be wrong, so we can't let experts fix problems". It's a cop-out; make a chat room for expert review or something, this is the highest visibility programming site out there, has millions of eyes on it that can find problems, why let that go to waste because "SE's edit system can't pull in experts"?

Comment: Perhaps if an answer is deemed to be 'wrong', it could be edited to provide a warning to that effect... that would provide substantial teaching opportunities as well. For the sake of consistency any major 'correction' should be then submitted as an entirely new answer.

Comment: Given that even after a popular meta post, the most popular answer still contains misinformation, I would say the *"let popular vote decide correctness"* ideal is a bit flawed.

Answer (score 49):

If an answer with incorrect or misleading information has sat there for a long time and a comment pointing out the misinformation has received many upvotes, that implies that if the original commenter had just written an answer instead with the correct information (and an explanation of why it is more correct than the other information), that answer could have accumulated all of those upvotes by now.

The problem with edits like this is that they bypass the voting system, so the current answer's score gets applied to new content which the community has not judged, so the new content has not earned that score. Yes, you the editor may know that the answer is wrong and your answer is right, but if your answer is deserving of a score of 50+ then the community can decide that by writing an answer so they can vote on it. Sure, the best time to have written that answer was 8 years ago, but the second-best time is today.

Therefore I've gone and written it up as a community wiki answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71104696/12299000).

Comment: "and a comment pointing out the misinformation has received many upvotes" - **it got 3**. It's only got 15 now because of all the meta attention. In the time it took for the comment to get 3 upvotes, the answer got 44.

Comment: Well, that just shows it's not too late for the correct information to receive upvotes, doesn't it? So what is the reason for not posting the correct information in an answer?

Comment: It shows that without a giant meta uproar, this kind of thing gets almost completely ignored, and even *with* a giant meta uproar, it still can't compete with the vote count of the wrong answer.

Comment: It certainly can't compete if you don't post it as an answer!

Comment: If I had simply posted another answer, it would be sitting at 0 or 1 upvotes now, as answer number 4 on the list, below the wrong answer, falsetru's answer, and that one mod-deleted answer that wouldn't have been mod-deleted without the meta uproar drawing attention. Maybe 10 people would scroll down that far in the next year.

Comment: A couple of points from my own experiences (admittedly over a shorter time on SO than you): I have written answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60159044/12299000) where the original answer from 2012 was deprecated in Python 3, the deprecation was pointed out in comments in 2012 and 2018 (with 6 and 4 upvotes respectively), but neither of those commenters bothered to write the correct information for Python 3 in an answer at the time. So I wrote the correct information in an answer in 2020 and since then it got 44 upvotes, comparable to the 55 upvotes of the outdated answer.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica so you are describing the fact that the voting system doesn't work (sometimes) and as a solution you are proposing to completely bypass it?

Comment: The second point: some of my answers have received multiple edits from individuals who *thought* what I had written was wrong, where if they had asked a comment to clarify then I could have cleared up their confusion without their incorrect edit showing on the page for the time it took me to revert their edits. Sure, we can agree that your information in this case is correct, but as a policy, "don't unilaterally change the information presented in answers" is a good one because an individual editor's judgement should not overrule the community's judgement (by voting) in general.

Comment: You posted as answer number 2, below a single answer that fits in less than a screen, that is 100% broken on Python 3. (Even the part that tries to use a key function doesn't work on Python 3, because `key` needs to be passed as a keyword argument.) An answer like that is much easier to compete with.

Comment: So basically, you're happy using your own forecast of how many votes your answer would get in order to justify not writing it. Isn't it better to just assume that (1) the correct information will be useful to people, and (2) if it's useful to people they'll upvote it? I'm not seeing any argument *against* writing it as an answer here, other than pessimism.

Comment: "Isn't it better to just assume that (1) the correct information will be useful to people, and (2) if it's useful to people they'll upvote it?" - no, because that completely ignores the massive difference in visibility.

Comment: (Posting another answer *would* have been the second thing I tried, if the edit got rolled back without a giant meta uproar, but then the giant meta uproar happened. Trying to post another answer with this mess ongoing would have risked downvotes from people thinking "this person has done a Bad Thing and I will downvote them as punishment".)

Comment: @Kaiido: All edits bypass the voting system. That doesn't make edits automatically wrong. If someone wants to correct typos in an answer, or clarify the wording, both approved reasons to edit, they *could* post a second answer instead and see how the votes go, but editing is so much more productive.

Comment: *"All edits bypass the voting system."* I disagree. Maybe there are a minority of users who would downvote (or decline to upvote) based on a spelling error, grammatical error, formatting problem, or some other trivial reason, but I certainly don't vote that way and I don't think most users vote that way. An edit to fix some problem like that doesn't bypass anyone's vote if they voted based on the information content and the edit doesn't change the information content. Likewise, an edit to fix a link that wasn't broken when people cast their votes, doesn't bypass those users' votes.

Comment: """the second best time is today""" - this does *not* mean it will *not* take another 8 years to reach the same vote count - and that's generous since it's not the top answer (depending on sort order) - it ***will*** almost certainly never gain as many upvotes. as for the new answer, linking to another answer for the rest of the explanation is far from ideal as a good post should be self-contained

Comment: tl;dr: posting a new answer is ***not*** a solution.

Comment: in other words, the ideal solution would be to have *some* avenue for improving an existing answer when posting a comment is not working. because frankly, i really don't think having incorrect information is a goal of SO

Comment: This answer focuses only on the voting and scoring which are relatively trivial side issues. The real problem is that nothing is being done about the content of a highly-upvoted-but-wrong answer, and the notion that posting a new correct answer resolves the issue is misguided. Can we have some recognition that fixing answers that are wrong is highly desirable in certain cases? Adding a comment or a new answer, and/or downvoting should not be the only options available for situations like this one. It's crazy that after intense review here, the bad answer is being left untouched.

Comment: @skomisa Fixing answers that are wrong is of course desirable. What's at issue is whether it is desirable for *other* users than the original author to change the information content and intent of their answer. I argue that that's not desirable in general, and the voting system is my rationale for that. Another reason is that the information content of an answer is considered attributable to the person named as its author, even if it has been edited by other users, and it's not necessarily fair on that person to "put words in their mouth" as it were, even if the words are correct.

Comment: @somebody *"the ideal solution would be to have some avenue for improving an existing answer when posting a comment is not working"* - This is a good point, of course, and I agree it would be good to have a community-agreed way of doing that; I just disagree with this way of doing it. It did occur to me that the edit in question would be totally acceptable if it was a community wiki, so perhaps the solution is to have some (fair) way to convert old, abandoned answers into CWs? I did some searches and didn't find this proposed before, so I'm not sure what the community would think about it.

Comment: @kaya3 OK, but in this case we are applying general guidelines where the specific circumstances make that approach inappropriate. Specifically: the answer is highly upvoted (and therefore inherently credible), the answer is wrong, the author was twice advised of this in comments but ignored them, and the author is still active on SO. Given all that, their question is fair game for correction. If they don't like the edits they can argue their case. But the bottom line is that we are knowingly leaving a bad but highly upvoted answer untouched. That's not good, and should be the primary concern.

Comment: One of the general rules for edits is they should not conflict with the original author's intent, and this is specifically a thing that edits are supposed to be rejected for if they do. So whether or not the edit follows some of the guidelines, it plainly doesn't follow all of them, and one of the rules it breaks is a pretty important one. On top of that, I would say the fact that the author is still active makes a stronger case that such an edit conflicts with their intent, because they are still around to edit it themselves in response to the criticism if they wanted to.

Comment: As for *"leaving a bad but highly upvoted answer untouched"*: most of the answer is good, and you seem to be taking the position that (1) downvotes don't count as "touching" it, and that (2) the solution must involve "touching" that answer. IMO, the primary concern should be that there is *an* answer with the correct information.

Comment: "One of the general rules for edits is they should not conflict with the original author's intent," citation needed. https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing doesn't mention "intent". Nor it does the small help when you are on the editing dialog. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066

Comment: @Braiam See [the official FAQ for all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11476/1135948): *"You **edit to make things better, clearer, more effective -- never to change meaning.**"* (emphasis in original). The fact that edits should not conflict with the author's intent is also very clear from the fact that "conflicts with the author's intent" is a reason that proposed edits should be rejected, as I pointed out. Also relevant from the FAQ, see [What is the etiquette for correcting old questions with incorrect answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5411/1135948).

Comment: Also from the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), under common reasons for editing: "To clarify the meaning of the post (without *changing* that meaning)" (emphasis in original). And from [the meta.SE answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/12299000) you linked: "The relevant guidelines here - the ones spelled out on the full editing page - are simple: - clarify meaning without changing it - *always* respect the original author" (emphasis in original)

Comment: @somebody "i really don't think having incorrect information is a goal of SO." - Yeah, it's probably not an explicit goal, but I think it's an inevitable side effect of SO's method of obtaining high quality answers: solicit answers from the community and let them vote for the best answer. The beauty of this method is that it is self-regulating. There are going to bad and incorrect answers, but that's ok and expected, because the rest of the system (primarily votes, but also comments, etc.) will take care of it.

Comment: @kaya3 meaning != intent. You are saying that one shouldn't conflict with the author intent, the quote you offer me says "meaning"

Comment: @Braiam OK, so are you actually proposing that the edit we're discussing about *doesn't* change the meaning of the answer, or are you just quibbling over whether "conflicts with author's intent" describes well enough the fact that the edit *does* change the meaning of the answer? If it's the latter, your quibble is [with language which appears verbatim in the "reject edit" dialog](https://i.imgur.com/CtqbKOT.png) when you are reviewing suggested edits, as I am now pointing out for the third time.

Comment: Words have meaning, not intent. Intent is something subjective. For example, you are trying to glean what is my intent in the last comment, but my only intent is that you provide a quote for the "intent" part. The meaning of my words don't change, but from those alone you can't grasp my intent. BTW, the reject reason explains "Even edits that _must make drastic changes_ should strive to _preserve the goals_ of the post's owner." This edit is a "drastic change", and still preserves the author "goals", which is to answer the question. Even when "intent" is used, it's not all encompassing.

Comment: So, using "intent" alone is not constructive, it needs a modifier that further clarifies what was the intent of the author of the reject reason: [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239950/213575).

Comment: In this context, "intent" means "intended meaning". Your quibble is over whether we can know what the author's intended meaning was since we only have the words they wrote. Well, they wrote that `tee` is more efficient than `list`, so we can **certainly** infer that their intended meaning was not the opposite of that, and therefore an edit which makes it say the opposite **definitely** conflicts with their intent. But seriously, if there is no point to your argument besides that you think I should have said "meaning" instead of "intent", then I just don't care. Go pick a fight somewhere else.

Comment: @kaya3 No, intent means literally "intent", not "intended meaning". You are ignoring the various examples where intent means literal "intent": "you won't always know what the intentions of the author were until he clarifies by commenting", "preserve the goals of the post's owner", etc. Intent was never about meaning, was about goals, objective, what the author tries to achieve with their post. Otherwise, why would anyone goes to such lengths to keep them separated? [In fact, rejecting outright the one that implies both meanings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/786174)

Comment: @kaya3 that means, that the presumed intent of the author of any answer to a question is to "solve the problem presented on the question", because that's literally the only reason why someone would post a valid answer. Trying to reason or second guess it yet another fools errand. So, please, stick to the facts. Do not try to reinterpret someone post so that it fits your desired argument. I provided plenty of examples of what Shog's intentions and the meaning behind the words selected. Respect that. Otherwise, this will not be a constructive argument to be had.

Comment: This is already not a constructive argument. It became non-constructive when you asked me for citations that you didn't actually want, instead of just saying "I think you should have said meaning instead of intent", which would have saved both of us a lot of time. As I said, I don't care if you think "intent" is the wrong word, go pick a fight somewhere else.

Comment: I asked you for citations and those citations actually weaken your argument since they are very explicit to say "meaning" rather than "intent", then you went to reinterpret them to fit your desired argument when I pointed it out. This is a dogmatic approach. You are explaining away any evidence that doesn't fit your argument, that's not constructive. I've tried several times to make you understand that "intent" != "meaning" and shown you examples where this kind of edits are not only allowed, but desired. Yet, you haven't considered that your argument is flawed or showed me where mine is.

Comment: You are basically [doing what Cerbus did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288802/is-it-ok-to-edit-the-question-to-change-the-authors-intention/288836#comment170521_288805) and worse, you are rejecting the other solution that "maybe you should communicate first with the author". In other words, for you any content that is posted on the site is set on stone and immutable by anyone other than the author, when the site in no unambiguous way tells you to go away if you aren't ok with your post being edited. [See second paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: Again, dude, I used the wording from the "reject edit" dialog that everyone who reviews suggested edits is familiar with. If you prefer to pretend "intent" is my word instead of a verbatim quote then there is nothing I can do to help you. Please stop wasting my time.

Comment: And again, the wording on reject edits says "goals". The goal of the author was to offer a solution to the problem, they messed up, and were misleading instead. The editor fixed that. At least, acknowledge that.

Comment: @Braiam I can see that "I don't care" and "stop wasting my time" have not brought you the satisfying sense of closure that you are seeking. As your friend, I would like to correct this by writing a story for you. \*ahem\*. *On the desk to kaya3's right, sat a notebook. It was a fancy leather-bound journal, emblazoned in gold with the title* OPINIONS. *He opened the book to about the middle page, which was titled "Opinions about what word should be used, which are very pertinent to the argument". Underneath, he wrote: "Braiam thinks the 'reject edit' dialog should say 'meaning' instead of ...*

Comment: *... 'intent'.". Having recorded for posterity Braiam's opinion in the tome, kaya3 closed the notebook and replaced it on the desk, breathing a sigh of relief; now, he would remember it for the rest of his life. The End.*

Answer (score 28):

Posting a comment, or another answer, would have accomplished nothing. Two people already posted comments about the issue I tried to address, and accomplished nothing. They got almost completely ignored. One of them posted on day 1 of the answer's existence, but in the over 7 years between when the comment was posted and when I saw it, it only got 3 upvotes. The answer got 44 during that time period. The answerer abandoned the post and never responded to anything.

Adding a third response to the pile wouldn't help. But my impression is that people have mostly made up their minds one way or the other about this, and rehashing the debate won't accomplish anything either, so how about this:

#### Proposal

Instead of my original edit, I propose a different edit. The original answer text is this:

> But if there are many elements, it's a better idea to create
> independent iterators using
> [`tee()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):
>
> ```
> import itertools
> it1, it2 = itertools.tee(db[3], 2) # create as many as needed
> ```
>
> Now we can loop over each one in turn:
>
> ```
> for e in it1:
>     print("doing this one time")
>
> for e in it2:
>     print("doing this two times")
> ```

The author has heard that `tee` helps save memory on long inputs, but has made a mistake about what circumstances that works in. It only works when you're iterating over all the tees together, so their positions in the data stream stay close to each other. Several people have pointed this out in the comments.

I propose to edit it to say this:

> Sometimes you can save memory over the list approach by using
> [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee). For use cases like
>
> ```
> l = list(iterator)
> for thing, next_thing in zip(l, l[1:]):
>     ...
> ```
>
> where you're iterating over several copies of the input "in sync", you
> can save memory by creating iterators with `tee`:
>
> ```
> import itertools
> it1, it2 = itertools.tee(iterator, 2) # create as many as needed
> next(it2)
> for thing, next_thing in zip(it1, it2):
>     ...
> ```
>
> `tee` consumes memory proportional to how far apart the tee iterators
> are in the data stream, so as long as the iterators don't get too far
> away from each other, this will save memory.

Is this good? Let's see what the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) has to say.

#### What the help center has to say

> All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons, and this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!

The post needed improvement, so I clicked "edit"! Let's keep reading.

> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear,
> relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of
> your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted
> users, this may not be the site for you.
>
> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to
> suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so. The original author of a
> question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of
> reputation level.
>
> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than
> you found it.

This edit is substantial and leaves the post better than I found it.

> Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

How does this edit compare to the "common reasons"? The edit

- could be argued to change the meaning (but less so than the previous edit),
- incorporates information previously only in the mostly-overlooked comments, and
- corrects the author's minor mistake about when `tee` saves memory.

Mostly good! But does it change the meaning? And is that a deal-breaker? Let's think about it.

Any edit necessarily changes the meaning of a post to some degree. Edits by the OP often change the meaning a lot, but even non-OP edits will change the meaning somewhat. One of the help-center-approved edit reasons is adding information from comments, and that changes the meaning. The meaning of the post before such an edit didn't include that extra information, and after the edit, it does.

The meaning of the existing version of this answer section is "use `tee` for nebulous benefits on long iterators". The meaning of the edited version is "use `tee` to save memory on long iterators in the specific type of situation where it helps". That seems good to me.

Anyway, the help center says to edit "If you see something that needs improvement". *Not* editing would violate that.

Comment: The fact that the `tee` operator is the wrong way to achieve that is a useful information _by itself_. From my pov, a new answer stating that and a simple edit with only a warning in the related answer with explanations  (and maybe a link to your new one) should have suffice. Many users may think of `tee` in this wrong way, and keeping the _bad_ answer with a warning should be better to let them see that.

Comment: I think what you are proposing here is a better edit. It provides a better example and better explanation. The previous edit, slightly changed intent, which was to demonstrate usage of `tee`. Your new edit keeps the same intent while fixing the small mistake.

Comment: @Dharman are you trying to say that the intent of the author was to offer misleading information? If that's the case it would be very not nice action and a disservice to the rest of the community.

Comment: @Braiam On the contrary.

Comment: This proposed edit is definitely much better than the previous one. Perhaps even better would be to *add* your proposed edit to the answer, so that the information you want readers to have is in the answer, and you're not really risking conflicting with the author's intent.

Comment: @cigien: But the answer would be incoherent that way. It would contain the original mistaken section about `tee`, followed by another section about `tee` that says `tee` only helps in situations unlike the situation in the first section.

Comment: Yeah, you might be right, it would be a tricky edit to make. Well, if you can't edit the answer in a way that somehow still preserves the author's opinion that their approach of using `tee` is a good idea, then I'm afraid you'll just have to accept it. I know, it's not ideal that you have to leave an answer that you firmly believe contains misleading information, but there's not much that can be done about it. One can only hope that readers look at comments, and dig deeper into what answers suggest, instead of blindly copy-pasting. Maybe the author will see this meta post, and edit their ans.

Comment: @cigien so, the SO community lost any say about the content that resides on the site? What happened to "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."? If we can't be trusted to correct misinformation on the site, the site content quality is done for. There's a limit to what voting can do as this answer shows (basically it did nothing), so without editing by trusted users there's no way we can make the internet a better place.

Comment: @Braiam Not at all, the community certainly has plenty of say in what content is on the site. However, changing the intent of the author is not an acceptable way to deal with misinformation (as covered in the help-center, and meta). The usual approaches to dealing with misinformation are voting, posting better content, and leaving comments. The text about collaborative editing is to allow for edits that improve typos, fix formatting, and other minor cleanup.

Comment: In general I don't agree with editing code in an answer, but in this specific case you have my sympathy. As you point out, _"The answerer abandoned the post and never responded to anything"_. That person is a high rep user who is still active on SO, and has had over seven years to address concerns raised by other users about their answer. While they are free to ignore users' criticisms, they shouldn't be immune to the consequences of doing that. Suggestions that you should post your own answer instead, or merely comment, would do very little to address the deficiency in the existing answer.

Comment: @cigien Re _"The usual approaches to dealing with misinformation are voting, posting better content, and leaving comments"_, that hasn't worked in this case because the author of the original answer chose to completely ignore the criticisms of their answer. Given that, I think that their editing their answer is a reasonable approach. If the user's answer is incorrect AND they don't bother to defend it, then their answer is fair game.

Comment: @skomisa The usual approach of "posting better content" (i.e. writing the correct information in another answer) wasn't tried, so you are simply wrong to say it hasn't worked in this case.

Comment: *"Posting ... another answer, would accomplish nothing."* But you justify this by saying that posting *comments* did not accomplish the desired outcome. You didn't try posting another answer.

Comment: @kaya3 I'm not "wrong". The person who wrote the original answer ignored criticism of their solution for years, and adding another answer would do not directly address criticisms of the existing answer. So an appropriate solution _in this specific case_, was to correct the deficient answer. I don't see anyone here arguing that the original answer was perfectly fine, or that the edits made to their code were wrong. Opposition seems based on SO conventions being broken by citing cherry picked quotes, even though the answer above above cites SO guidance that was followed when making the edit.

Comment: @Zilog80 "it's useful information *by itself*" does not mean "it is a complete answer to the question by itself"...

Comment: @kaya3 "The usual approach of "posting better content" (i.e. writing the correct information in another answer) wasn't tried" that's totally inaccurate. It was tried with a [more sensitive issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293930/792066) and it took years for votes to do things, while edits were immediate.

Comment: @Braiam I'm going to be charitable and assume you simply missed the words "in this case" in both my comment and the comment I responded to. We were talking about this specific case, not the general case, and I certainly haven't claimed it has never been tried ever in any case...

Comment: This is absolutely the best of both worlds IMO. Those arguing that this still "changes author intent" miss the fact the _no one gains anything by keeping around wrong answers_. **We all lose when answers are wrong**. This edit _preserves_ author intent by explaining the actual usefulness of `tee` as a possible solution, while also correcting the false, clearly unintentional misunderstanding of the mechanism by the original author, which benefits absolutely no one.

Comment: @kaya3 I will be charitable and assume that you are trying to say that what didn't work and hasn't worked in years, will suddenly work today just because. Lets be real, if it hasn't worked in years and nothing changed significantly in the structure and process of the site, expecting a different result _in this case_ is a fool's errand.

Comment: @Braiam I think I can summarise your argument as that you are pessimistic that writing correct information in new answers will work in cases like these. There are certainly cases where it hasn't worked and there are also certainly cases where it has worked. Either way it is simply true to say that it *wasn't tried in this case*. I responded to an argument based on the premise that it was tried in this case and didn't work, to point out that that premise is false. Verifying that said premise is false doesn't take charity, just observation.

Comment: @kaya3 I'm not pessimistic, I've see the writing in the wall. I've seen it on several sites too, where I was the one with the specific knowledge and the community overruled me on something I've demonstrated I'm expert at. Heck [even moderators have found the current _status quo_ ridiculous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339101/the-community-vs-the-domain-expert#comment419011_339127). It's not compatible to have static artifacts that can't be improved and be a library of high quality Q&A. No content should be sacred on the site.

Comment: Why not just flag an answer you believe to be wrong for deletion? It's a soft-delete anyway, so it can be reverted. Assuming, of course, that you can prove why it's a wrong answer(like you do in your edit or here).

Comment: @cst1992 Because those flags *will* be declined: it’s been repeatedly established that incorrect answers are not to be dealt with by flags, but rather by downvotes.

Comment: @cst1992 Also, if the handling mod *does* decide to delete it (which they won't on a technical issue), it's not a soft-deletion. Regular users can't vote to undelete posts that are mod-deleted.

Answer (score 8):

I posed the question to the editor:

> was your intent to edit because you generally agree with the author but you thought their description would be misinterpreted, or do you believe the answer to be wrong and or detrimental to the community?

The response will be interesting but not relevant. The edit changed the *fundamental* approach, specifically it changed the iteration concept and the specific functions used. Broadly, it changed the explanation and the code example.

It is acceptable to fix typos, change syntax formatting, or replace outdated implementations with current best practices using the same libraries. But to change the actual code in the answer should be raised as an alternate answer.

It is also acceptable to re-phrase wording if the original intent is maintained, citations to external sources can be added, and it is common to see a footnote added that might further explore the same topics raised in the answer, but you shouldn't introduce new concepts or logical thought processes — that would constitute a new answer.

In that answer, you are expected to give a thorough review of the currently accepted answer or other existing answers. You should also provide justification for why your answer should be considered superior. If you feel strongly enough, you should also downvote the accepted answer. If your analysis is accepted as justified by the community, other members will vote up your response and downvote the other.

*It is not for us here to discuss the technical content of the question or the edit, only the types of changes in the edit itself.*

Side by side the former and the edited answer are *very* different, both in the explanation and the code example, so it was correct to revert the edit.

---

Perhaps the most important reason for this to be a new answer, even if it is similar, is that it would not be fair to expect the original poster to respond to comments about the new content, as the editor you do not get the notifications for the comments.

We need to be held accountable for the code examples and explanations that we publish, the only way to do that is to post your idea, especially if it is similar to others, so that you can be directly engaged for feedback if needed.

Comment: Thanks @skomisa I changed it to a quote, which is also not correct, but it really is important and it was a hard lesson for me to learn myself. I used to edit posts instead of new answers, because I didn't want the rep and just wanted to help the community, but no matter how technically correct the new content might be, and edit like that _should_ always be rejected or reverted. Also you need to be available to be held accountable for your idea, its not fair for OP to cop feedback on our edit.

Comment: why would you pigeon hole yourself to such an inane set of rules that benefit no one. It seems to me the main defenders of not editing are people who have had bad edits done on them, and are annoyed at having to go back to it. Clearly, the rules need to be changed and not the fact of fixing mistakes. Finally, abandoned posts should have all editing rules relaxed after 6months/1year. Abandoned and wrong comments are only fixed by the passerbys in EDITS and no other system does anything.

Comment: It takes a while to learn the value in this. What is the point of editing at all? Are you a higher authority on the subject then the author? Who is going to validate your input and finally who is going to read it. These _rules_ as I've postulated them are a reflection on the way that we all interact with SO as a community. When you edit you are altering the conversation but taking no accountability for it. Many answer edits should just be closed, especially if they are very old or have significant votes and replaced with a more current/correct answer if you have one.

Answer (score 2):

Making a substantive edit to someone else's answer is tricky.
Making a substantive edit to an old, longstanding, highly-upvoted answer is even trickier.

Sometimes, it's true, an answer (even though longstanding and upvoted) contains an egregious error, and that error has gone uncorrected by the original answerer for so long that I'll be bold enough to edit it.

But sometimes, the egregiousness of an error is in the eyes of the beholder.  Stack Overflow has both askers and answerers at many different levels.  Sometimes, an answer's departure from
100% correct, complete technical accuracy is perfectly acceptable to some majority of readers.  In that case, the departure is not an "egregious error", it is a "simplification".

I'm not saying that's what happened here, but it might be.  The application of `tee` worked, but it might not have been efficient — in fact, depending on the size of the input, it might have been unacceptably inefficient.  So the question, is, does that make `tee` wrong as an answer?  Or, if `tee` is suggested as an answer, is it vital that the answer be accompanied by a disclaimer?  And what should the tone of the disclaimer be? Should it be, "This answer will work fine for small inputs, but beware that it will consume lots of memory for large inputs"? Or should it be, "`tee` is only acceptable for demonstration purposes, in tiny, toy programs; you would never want to use it like this in a real program"?  I don't know.

What I do know is that sometimes (though again, I'm not saying it happened here) expert answerers are so eager to show off their expertise that they forcibly inject utterly unnecessary third-order nuances into what ought to have been a nice, easy (albeit simplified) discussion of a newbie's basic problem. Sometimes, it's true, those nuances are so vital, and ignorance of them can be so destructive, that it's important to get them in newbies' faces early.  But sometimes, they really are distractions, that leave a newbie more bewildered than enlightened.

Again, I'm not saying that's what happened here.  But I think that the Help Center's blithe statement that "If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!" should be taken with a grain of salt.  It can be really hard to be confident that the improvement you have in mind would, in fact, be viewed as an improvement by the answer's original author, or by its intended audience.

Comment: The situation is pretty much the exact opposite. `tee` is not a simplification. It is *more* complicated to use than `list`, and I don't just mean more complicated to use right (though it is) - it's more complicated to use *at all*. Used wrong, it also takes more time and more memory than `list`. Removing `tee` from the answer would *be* the newbie-friendly simplification.

Comment: While you are correct that making a _"substantive edit to someone else's answer is tricky"_, in this particular case the original poster had been made aware of problems with their answer years ago, and chose to do nothing about it. That is, neither refute (or even acknowledge) those criticisms, nor modify their answer. In that situation, if nothing is done a highly upvoted answer will be giving incorrect information in perpetuity. And all those past upvotes give the answer added authority. Surely, it's better for the SO community to correct the answer, rather than post an alternative one?

Comment: If this were **Wikipedia**, I would remove any references to `tee` entirely. It is incorrect in most scenarios, and one shouldn't talk about it all.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq interesting take, considering that this site aims to be wikipedia in the collaborative editing aspect.

Comment: All edits are supposed to be substantive.

Answer (score 0):

I was cleaning my tabs, so I took this time to revisit this post so I can finally close the tab, two years later to see the results of our actions. Well, as expected, the popular opinion is still ineffective. The competing "right" answer not only do not overtake the "wrong" answer, it will be left in the dust. Meta participation helped it to rise above the other answer, but can't beat the popularity of the top one. The answer using tee still gets more votes year over year compared to the other answers.

This demonstrate something that should be obvious on hindsight, but seems that needs to be explicitly needed to say:

The readers of the answers are not qualified to tell which is better between two competing answers that *seemingly* solve the issue, and will default to the popular one. They are looking for answers to question because, most of them, do not know any solution, less how to evaluate which solution is the best.

Readers or consumers of answers only goal is something that seems to solve their immediate issue, and nothing more. In the last year alone it got more upvotes by a factor of 3, therefore our only conclusion is that readers are finding the top answer more helpful. Except that this conclusion is wrong if you consider that they don't read past the top one!

This has lead me to reiterate some things that I've hinted several times before in several other discussions about related topics:

- When thinking about how answers are ranked, they are by far ranked the lowest common denominator: that it *works*.
- Therefore users/readers/consumers only scroll past the top answer if either they know that the answer is not *"right"* (which is very rare) or the top answer flat-out doesn't work.
- Users looking for answers rarely know what a bad but working solution is.
- To herd users towards the better solutions, we have to manage our content with more explicit intent. If we want the better solution to be at the top, we can't restrict ourselves to rely on *ad populum*/voting, since that ignores the 3 points above.

Comment: I'm not sure which answer you consider the "right" one here. If you mean the community wiki answer, it gives a one-sentence explanation for only part of the question, and then offers a clarification of what is "wrong" about the "wrong" answer. And really, the "wrong" answer isn't wrong in the usual sense. The `tee` solution will certainly work, it's just that the supposed benefit often doesn't turn out like one might expect. When it *is* appropriate, it's brilliant - clearly better than just building a list, and would otherwise be greatly underpromoted and underappreciated.

Comment: IMHO the "right" answer is the one I wrote. I actually covered all the reasonable ways to approach the problem, explained pros and cons of each, covered the relevant concepts and theory, and avoided several minor accuracies in Mateen's attempt at the same. However, it's practically an encyclopedia. And, yes, it is even further down the page.

Answer (score -11):

This is more or less, vandalism. A user with edit privileges changed the intent of an answer, and yes, that edit should be reverted (and it was).

If the answer is really problematic, and poses security risks, then a better approach would've been to summarize this in a note added at the beginning of the answer, and leave the original content untouched. This way, people are warned about the downsides of using the answer, while still being able to use it if they want.

Comment: This answer's got something for both sides of the debate to downvote, so I don't think it's going to get much support. People in favor of bigger edits will disagree with the first paragraph, while people against bigger edits will think edits like the second paragraph proposes are bad too.

Comment: Agreed with the second paragraph, warning notes are the way to go

Comment: Very balanced answer. A bigger question might be how to detect this kind of vandalism more effectively. There might be much more of it out there left uncorrected.

Comment: I despise those kind of meta edits, stuff that starts with "note", "update", "warning", etc. If information is bad or stale, it has no place on the Q&A so the post is either fixed or removed. A site that tries to be the library of high quality question and answers, need not have content that doesn't meet the bar.

Comment: The first part of that answer is fine, but the info in the end section starting from "But if there are many elements, it's a better idea to create independent iterators using tee()" is misleading, and the demo code at the end is *exactly* the situation when using the fancy `tee()` function is *worse* than using a simple `list()` call. It's not a security risk, but it's definitely misleading because it makes a blanket claim that `tee` is better than `list`, and that's only true under special conditions.

Comment: Edits should not be used to add comments to a post; that's what *comments* are for. "This answer is suboptimal" is a comment, it is a response to the answer, not an answer to the question.

Comment: @kaya3 But "This answer is suboptimal because of X" can be edited in any content like "You could do Y but that would be suboptimal because of X" and all we would do is improving the content. It doesn't really take anything away from the answer, if possibly only complements it.

Comment: @Trilarion This answer is proposing that one should edit to add what is basically a comment, as a separate note distinguished from the rest of the answer, leaving the answer's content (including the part which contradicts the added note) unchanged. That's what I responded to.

Comment: @kaya3 the note should be added only in extreme cases, otherwise the answer should be left untouched, and another answer be added instead. And I think this particular case can be considered as extreme due to the number of upvotes for a poorly performing solution.

Comment: @Cristik "...the number of upvotes for a poorly performing solution..." Might be fitting for the outdated answers discussion then which proposed version labels for answers.

Comment: Agreed, @Trilarion, there are other ways to cope with answers that are not optimal, other than vandalising them.

Comment: @Cristik "vandalising"? Really? We are fixing an inaccuracy, not defacing it. In the end, it will result in a better artifact, not a worse one.

Comment: @Braiam Stale answers are still useful. I have found myself on several occasions needing to support severely outdated technology. In one instance, even the author of the tool had ceased distributing its documentation. It can be very difficult to find any help in cases like these. I'd much rather there not be Correctness Crusaders riding around editing away all of the stale answers. Some people need them.

Comment: You will prefer incorrect information? What? I want correct information, not incorrect one. Also, that you have found some of its answers useful, doesn't mean that some aren't or that they can't be improved. This site is based on the principle that anyone can edit anyone's post. In fact, **it tells you to go away** if you don't feel comfortable with that "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you." So, all hail the correctness crusaders!

Comment: @DanielSchilling When I google about iterators, I don't want correct information about tea, nor incorrect information about `tee`. Even if there exists one person out there who is really, really thirsty or hasn't heard about `itertools.tee`. Reducing the *average* time spent going through irrelevant or incorrect information is why Google exists in the first place.

Comment: @Braiam by that logic we should not allow more that one answer to a question, and force people to keep changing that firstly posted answer. Fixing bugs in the code is OK, replacing the answer with a whole different solution is not, a dedicated answer is the way to go for the latter. Simple as that. Can't cope with the fact that an answer you don't like has many upvotes? Maybe SO is not the place for you.

Comment: @Cristik funny that you say that, because that was the ideal scenario ["Whatever happened to the logic that, in an ideal world, a question would have a single, highly-upvoted, community-audited, well-maintained, canonical answer that would be easy to find?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339101/the-community-vs-the-domain-expert#comment419011_339127).

Comment: Interesting point of view, @Braiam, thanks for the link. But wouldn't that require to have members that hold the absolute truth, and only those to be allowed to post answers? Otherwise we'd end up with numerous edit wars with members fighting over the same answer.

Comment: @Cristik no, because "truth" (or more accurately, technical correctness) is fluid and it changes. That's why we have trouble with obsolete answers. If there isn't any restriction in updating posts as they age, you will always have a chance to have a correct, up to date answer to the question. But if you restrict that, then you will remove that opportunity forever. BTW, edits wars aren't usually about those, [but about dogma, between members that try to make answer better and others that hold that post once written are set into stone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/170521).

Comment: Note that the suggestion there was to have polite communication, not to escalate the issue, not to argue about the rules, but to have a respectable conversation about what the content should be instead of entrenching yourself into a position.

Comment: @Braiam but we have the voting system for that, once an answer is no longer valid it will stop receiving upvotes, or accumulate downvotes, while the newer, and up-to-date-with-the-technology, answer be getting upvotes. Seems people are forgetting about this elemental rule that's part of SO since inception.

Comment: Heck, SO has even recently added the "outdated answers" feature, which was made especially for situations like this. It still baffles me why do some people keep fighting the system instead of trying to improve it.

Comment: @Cristik HAHAHAHAHAHA, [read all the links on this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416012/why-was-this-answer-heavily-edited-and-should-it-be-reverted/416013?noredirect=1#comment894916_416012) but let me spoil you a bit: no, it doesn't work. Also, outdated answer? The answer isn't outdated, it was misleading from the moment it got posted, tee never has done what the answer claims it does.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't agree with you on this @Braiam. The answer in discussion indeed had a mistake, and the mistake was around the performance implications of using `tee`, not the code itself. The code should've been left unaltered, and the editor did a bad move by rewriting the code.

Comment: And why should it? SO has made abundantly clear that you give away any right to any code (or content for that matter) due license, and then gave everyone else authorization to freely edit the post as long as it makes it better. How the edit doesn't make the post better? Where does it say that I can't make the post better?

Comment: That still doesn't make it a nice move, @Braiam. There were other nicer ways to achieve a similar result. The editor chose to go the "my way or the highway", and that's not OK in a democratic community.